# prepareForSegue an error Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have simple code:

```
var searchResults1: [(name:String, description:String)]=[]
var searchResults2: [(name:String, description:String)]=[]
var searchResults3: [(name:String, description:String)]=[]

var situation1 = [(name: "qq", description: "ww"), (name: "ee", description: "rr"), (name: "tt", description: "yy"), (name: "aa", description: "ss")]
var situation2 = [(name: "qq", description: "ff"), (name: "gg", description: "hh"), (name: "jj", description: "kk"), (name: "ll", description: "ii")]
var situation3 = [(name: "zz", description: "xx"), (name: "cc", description: "vv"), (name: "bb", description: "nn"), (name: "mm", description: "as"), (name: "we", description: "sd"), (name: "xc", description: "gf")]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return "I"
    case 1:
        return "II"
    case 2:
        return "III"
    case 3:
        return "IV"
    case 4:
        return "V"
    case 5:
        return "VI"
    case 6:
        return "VII"
    case 7:
        return "VIII"
    case 8:
        return "IX"
    case 9:
        return "X"
    case 10:
        return "XI"
    case 11:
        return "XII"

    default:
        return nil
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 12
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
 indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            cell!.textLabel.text = searchResults1[indexPath.row].name

        } else {
            cell!.textLabel.text = situation1[indexPath.row].name



        }

        return cell!
    }


    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            cell!.textLabel.text = searchResults2[indexPath.row].name

        } else {
              cell!.textLabel.text = situation2[indexPath.row].name

        }
        return cell!
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            cell!.textLabel.text = searchResults3[indexPath.row].name

        } else {

        cell!.textLabel.text = situation3[indexPath.row].name

        }
        return cell!
    }
    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.searchResults1.count
        } else {

            return situation1.count }


    case 1:
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.searchResults2.count
        } else {
            return situation2.count }

    case 2:

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.searchResults3.count
        } else {
            return situation3.count }

            default:
        return 0
        }
    }




func filterContentForSearchText (searcText: String) {

    searchResults1 = situation1.filter{($0.name as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searcText)")}
    searchResults2 = situation2.filter{($0.name as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searcText)")}
    searchResults3 = situation3.filter{($0.name as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searcText)")}
 }


func searchDisplayController(controller:UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath){
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }

}
```

It was work good.

When I click on the cell searchResultsTableView error output: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Sample code function prepareForSegue:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
        var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!

        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:

            if self.searchDisplayController!.active {
                var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                var destViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
                destViewController.title = searchResults1[indexPath!.row].name
                destViewController.situation = searchResults1[indexPath!.row]
            }
            else {
                var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                let destViewController:DetailViewController! = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
                destViewController.title = situation1[indexPath!.row].name
                destViewController.situation = situation1[indexPath!.row]
            }
        case 1:
            if self.searchDisplayController!.active {
                var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                var destViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
                destViewController.title = searchResults2[indexPath!.row].name
                destViewController.situation = searchResults2[indexPath!.row]

            }
            else {
                var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                let destViewController:DetailViewController! = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
                destViewController.title = situation2[indexPath!.row].name
                destViewController.situation = situation2[indexPath!.row]
            }

        default:
            break
        }


        }
```

Can you suggest how I must modify the function prepareForSegue?

Link to project in DropBox https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3yeowjurweo3xdo/AAAh7S-N89XPSqi-Xr8M5WmPa?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: When you're getting an exception thrown, it's really helpful to provide the full stack trace (shown in the debug navigator) and point out the exact line where the exception happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     1.  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: cell!)

     2.  if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {


        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell

        var ip = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell);
        if (ip == nil) {
            ip = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForCell(cell);
        }

        var indexPath = ip!
        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `performSegueWithIdentifier` call passes `self` as the `sender` parameter:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
```

Your `prepareForSegue` method expects the sender to be a UITableViewCell:

```
let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
```

So I'd guess the crash is on that line, where the cast will fail, as your UITableView-derived class won't be castable to a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should I do to make a bridge between the search results and DetailViewController?

Comment: Well, you should probably be looking up the cell you need with 
`cellForRowAtIndexPath` and passing that as the sender to `performSegueWithIdentifier`, or maybe just use 
`indexPathForSelectedRow` in `prepareForSegue` to look up the selected row directly, rather than using the `sender`... Up to you, really.

Comment: Thanks! Received the following function: 

if self.searchDisplayController!.active {
var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
var destViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
destViewController.situation = searchResults1[indexPath!.row]                           
}

Comment: When I click on a cell of search results of section 1 everything is OK.
When I click on a cell of search results of section 2, I get the error: fatal error: Array index out of rank.
I understand that this is connected with:
destViewController.situation = searchResults1[indexPath!.row].
I can not make the transition to a DetailViewController to searchResults2, searchResults3.
What advise do?